# Multiple Windows in Python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a Program, in which u are able to open a seperate testing/debug window. Like, a second window including some buttons to affect the main window. I already tried a few things and i am able to open two seperate windows but whatever i am trying to draw is drawn in the main window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def debugWindow():
    dbWin = tk.Tk()
    dbWin.title("Debug")
    btn = tk.Button(text="Test")
    btn.pack()
    dbWin.mainloop()

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Mainwindow")
btn2 = tk.Button(text="Start debug Window", command=debugWindow)
btn2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

So that's what i tried, but as i said the second button renders in the first window.
Also i am pretty new to Python so if this is not the way u normally do it, please correct me. I am still learning :) And also sorry for my english, i am not a native speaker.

Comment: You want to use `Toplevel()` for that second window - calling `Tk()` a second time does give you a second window, but it lives in an entirely separate GUI environment that cannot interact with the original environment.  To put widgets in a specific window (or other container), pass it as the first parameter to the widget.

Comment: @Zuckerpapa As @ jsonharper said change `btn = tk.Button(text="Test")` to `btn = tk.Button(dbWin, text="Test")` to tell `tkinter` that `btn`'s master should be the second window (otherwise it assumes that the first window is the master).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the button stay on the window called dbWin ,then, instead of using:

```
btn = tk.Button(text="Test")
```

which python assumes that the button is suppose to go on the main window,
use:

```
btn = tk.Button(dbWin, text="Test")
```

Using this will specifically assign the second parameter thus allowing your button to go on the window dbWin

(credit to those who said this before me in the comments)

Comment: Isn't this what @jasonharper and I said in the comments?

Comment: @TheLizzard: if you want credit for an answer, you need to write an answer, not a comment. Don't fault someone else for creating an answer that has the same information as a comment. In this specific case, you don't know if they got the answer from your comment or if they simply knew the answer and submitted it.

Comment: @BryanOakley Given that it is 8 min after jasonharper posted the comment, it isn't right to take full credit for the answer. It is possible that it took DavidLiu 8 min to work out the problem and type the answer but I don't think that is likely. I think that giving credit is a must. It is fine if you disagree with me but I will still try to give credit where it is due

Comment: @TheLizzard: There's nothing wrong with someone writing a correct answer that happens to coincide with your comment. If you want credit, write an answer rather than a comment. Yes, they should give credit, but you shouldn't automatically assume they copied your comment. You're accusing them without any evidence.

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't think it is a coincidence given that it 8 min and 25 sec after jasonharper wrote that comment. I decided that writing my own answer wouldn't be respectful to jasonharper as he found the problem in OP's code first. There is no way of getting evidence so I am using probabilities.